# excel link to another sheet in same document without using filename?

Tags: microsoft-excel

This formula does exactly what I want:

```
=HYPERLINK("[!Monitoring Profile Matrix v2 (In Progress).xlsx]Metrics!3:3", "POWR01")
```

However, if I rename the document, I'm assuming all my links will break.  I tried this:

```
=HYPERLINK("Metrics!3:3", "POWR01")
```

And it says it can't find the target document.

So, how can I make a hyperlink to another sheet in the same workbook without using the filename explicitly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to include the filename.

However, you can use the `CELL` function to get the current workbook name, which you can then use in your hyperlink formula.  It's a little cumbersome, because the function returns other parts that you have to trim out, but it does make it possible, and will mean the links don't break if you rename the file.

[Here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/excel-help/insert-the-current-excel-file-name-path-or-worksheet-in-a-cell-HA010342623.aspx) are some examples. Note that in the function

```
=CELL("filename")
```

the word `filename` is a literal and should NOT be replaced by a filename.

Comment: Yikes!  Maybe I'll make a hidden cell and reference the filename that way instead of using that monster formula every time.  Thanks!